# Appending 3 two-dimensional matrices using R

Tags: r, matrix

I have three two-dimensional matrices in R. I want to *merge* them to get a final array. Would it be possible to help with a sample code in R?

To be specific, let's say I've the following matrices:

```
Matrix 1
1;  2;  3;
4;  5;  6;
7;  8;  9; 

Matrix 2
A;  B;   C;
D;  E;   F; 
G;  H;   I;

Matrix 3
P;  Q;  R; 
S;  T;  U;
V;  W;  X;
```

The resulting matrix that I would like to see is:

```
 Matrix 4
 1;A;P 2;B;Q 3;C;R
 4;D;S 5;E;T 6;F;U
 7;G;V 8;H;W 9;I;X
```

Note that the dimension of the matrix isn't fixed but it's guaranteed that the sizes of all of the matrices are the same.

To the  Matrix4, I want to add a constant to each element. So Matrix 5 would be

```
 Matrix 5
 X;1;A;P X;2;B;Q X;3;C;R
 X;4;D;S X;5;E;T X;6;F;U
 X;7;G;V X;8;H;W X;9;I;X
```

Once this is done, I would like to convert the Matrix into a list

```
 X;1;A;P 
 X;2;B;Q 
 X;3;C;R
 X;4;D;S 
 X;5;E;T 
 X;6;F;U
 X;7;G;V 
 X;8;H;W 
 X;9;I;X
```

Froma bigger picture, what Im trying is , I have 3 files where data is linked by position in the matrix. Once the data linkage is done as shown in Matrix 5, position really doesnt matter as the data is appended together. Im trying to get the final result that can be processed.

Comment: Is the final matrix 3x3 or 3x9?

Comment: The final matrix is 3X3. The semicolon is part of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a constant "B" and returning a list of entries:

```
m <- matrix(1:4, 2)
l <- list("B", m, m, m)
as.list(Reduce(function(m1, m2) paste(m1, m2, sep = ";"), l))
[[1]]
[1] "B;1;1;1"

[[2]]
[1] "B;2;2;2"

[[3]]
[1] "B;3;3;3"

[[4]]
[1] "B;4;4;4"
```

Although I would suggest to simply use a vector returned by

```
Reduce(function(m1, m2) paste(m1, m2, sep = ";"), l)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
do.call(cbind,lapply(seq_len(ncol(m1)),
      function(i) paste(m1[,i], m2[,i], m3[,i], sep=';')))
#     [,1]    [,2]    [,3]   
#[1,] "1;A;P" "2;B;Q" "3;C;R"
#[2,] "4;D;S" "5;E;T" "6;F;U"
#[3,] "7;G;V" "8;H;W" "9;I;X"
```

Or

```
`dim<-`(do.call(paste,c(mget(paste0('m',1:3)), sep=';')), dim(m1))
 #      [,1]    [,2]    [,3]   
 #[1,] "1;A;P" "2;B;Q" "3;C;R"
 #[2,] "4;D;S" "5;E;T" "6;F;U"
 #[3,] "7;G;V" "8;H;W" "9;I;X"
```

Or

```
 mNew <- m1
 mNew[] <- do.call(sprintf, c(mget(paste0('m', 1:3)), fmt='%s;%s;%s'))
 mNew
 #      [,1]    [,2]    [,3]   
 #[1,] "1;A;P" "2;B;Q" "3;C;R"
 #[2,] "4;D;S" "5;E;T" "6;F;U"
 #[3,] "7;G;V" "8;H;W" "9;I;X"
```

#### Update

If we need to append a constant ('X') to all the elements of 'mNew'

```
mNew[] <-  paste("X", mNew, sep=';')
mNew
#      [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
#[1,] "X;1;A;P" "X;2;B;Q" "X;3;C;R"
#[2,] "X;4;D;S" "X;5;E;T" "X;6;F;U"
#[3,] "X;7;G;V" "X;8;H;W" "X;9;I;X"
```

Converting to 'list' is not clear.  We could use `split` to split the elements either by 'row' or 'column', i.e.

```
 split(mNew, col(mNew))
 split(mNew, row(mNew))
```

To convert the individual elements in 'mNew' to list element,

```
 as.list(mNew)
```

#### data

```
m1 <- t(matrix(1:9, ncol=3))
m2 <-t( matrix(LETTERS[1:9], ncol=3))
m3 <-t( matrix(LETTERS[16:24], ncol=3))
```

Comment: May I ask you to add one more feature in the answer. To the final answer, I want to add a constant to each element in the matrix i.e. instead of 1;A;P it should be X;1;A;P , instead of 2:B;Q, it should be X;2:B;Q  . Also, the final matrix should be converted to a list i.e Im not worried about the position anymore

Comment: I updated the question as I couldnt explain the same in the comments. Sorry for multiple roundtrips

Comment: @Vaya I guess you want the individual elements to be converted to list elements.  So, simply `as.list(mNew)` will do it.  Please check the update

Comment: One more question: You have provided 3 methods to do the same task. If the matrix is 10,000 by 10,000 matrix, would there be a difference in response time?

Comment: @Vaya I am guessing `sprintf` with `'dim<-'` to be faster.  Not tested though.  You can try benchmarking (`?system.time`) each of the methods on a bigger dataset.